Get comments and likes on linkedin shares
Can we get all comments on posts made by someone else?
I'm trying to get comments using below endpoint https://api.linkedin.com/rest/socialActions/{encoded urn of share}/comments
but I get
{
    "message": "member is unauthorized on urn:li:activity:id",
    "status": 403
}

Can anyone help if there's any way we can fetch comments on posts made by someone else?

Is the post public and viewable by you?

@cryptic_hash : yes post is public and it's visible by me.
here's the official doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/shares/comments-api?view=li-lms-2024-04&tabs=http#get-comments-on-shares

In that case your api token might not be properly scoped. Can you verify if you have r_member_social permission in your auth token?
